# How can I get current ssh key fingerprint?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a nodejs app on Heroku.

How can I get the current ssh key fingerprint?

Not my own heroku app public ssh keys what I need. I want to git push to other Heroku
app, so I would need the current ssh key used by Heroku to send its public version to the other Heroku app.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have your old private key, there is no way to recover it. Because you upload only your public key. However, if you want to reaccess your repositories, you can do `heroku keys:add` and it will generate a new key pair and upload it to Heorku.